# SharePoint command in Powershell to list custom columns

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I've created a couple of extra columns in SharePoint: Obsolete as True/False and Review Date
In Powershell I can run this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -force | Select-Object Mode, Name, CreationTime | ft
```

How do I include the Obsolete and Review Date columns as objects in the list command?

How can I also update the value of the Obsolete and Review Date custom columns in Powershell with using the similar command:

```
$(Get-Item xxx.jpg).lastaccesstime=$(Get-Date)
```

[image]
[image]
Thanks

Comment: If you are selecting object, I think it automatically converts to a table anyways so `ft` is kinda redundant I think... Your question isn't clear... Why not use `select-object 'Mode', 'Name', 'CreationTime', 'Obsolete', 'Review Date'`? Can you clarify more?

Comment: Thanks, specifying object: 'Obsolete' doesn't return the values that are set in SharePoint. Is there another object name reference to specify. My question is to list in a table all the values set in SharePoint for the 2 custom columns. Then I want to be able to update the Obsolete value for a large number of files.

Comment: Without ft, it displays it as  tabular list for each file

Comment: I've updated the original question post with a screen capture of the SharePoint Custom Columns and the PowerShell list output.

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo to use PnPPowershell to read SharePoint list items.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

```
#region Variables 
$Username = "user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "Password" 
$siteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee"
#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

#(Get-PnPListItem -List MyList4 -Fields "Title","Obsolete","Review_x0020_Date").FieldValues| Format-Table
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "MyList4" -Fields Title,Obsolete,Review_x0020_Date
$items | %{new-object PSObject -Property @{Title=$_["Title"];Obsolete=$_["Obsolete"];ReviewDate=$_["Review_x0020_Date"]}}| select Title,Obsolete,ReviewDate
Write-Host "-----------"
```